# string needs to be used as column

Tags: postgresql

dynamic query not working properly. It is throwing error.

i tried with the same approach and using %I,%L,%S .

```
do $$
declare
v_out text;
v_inp text := '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}';
begin
execute format('select %s from tab',v_inp) into v_out;
raise info 'out: %',v_out;
exception
when others then
raise info  'error mssg %',sqlerrm;
end $$;
```

Getting Error: column "col1" does not exist

Actual: table and colmn both exist and the query is working fine

select '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}' from tab;

Comment: It doesn't exist at that point in time and in that context. Where is it supposed to get `col1` from? There's no table query in that statement.

Comment: tab is the tablename here . iTs  a sample.
table query is also there which is dynamic

Comment: This is the part that's erroring: `v_inp text := '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}';` - you can't just say "trim(col1)", because pg is going to try to trim some column or variable called "col1", which doesn't exist as there is no variable with that name, and that statement isn't reading from a table, so "col1" doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: select '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}' from tab; this is working fine for me. 
And If the code is having issue then how to get the make the dynamic query which gives the same output as 
select '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}' from tab;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this statement:

```
v_inp text := '{"id" : "1"'||trim(col1)||'}';
```

Postgres will execute/resolve `trim(col1)` at the time of the variable assignment, because that bit is not part of the string, it's a sql command and its result is what is concatenated with the string which is assigned to the variable. As there is no "col1" at that point, it fails.

Since you're trying to create a dynamic query, you want it to be executed later, during the table read, not at the time of variable assignment. Therefore that bit must be a string, which becomes sql at the time of dynamic statement execution.

That can be accomplished by escaping the single quotes (by double quoting):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
        var1 TEXT := '''{"id":"'' || TRIM(t) || ''"}''';
        query TEXT;
BEGIN
        query := FORMAT('SELECT %s FROM table', var1);
        RAISE NOTICE '%', query;
END $$
```

Result:

`SELECT '{"id":"' || TRIM(t) || '"}' FROM table`

(Or in your case, `v_inp text := '''{"id" : "1"''||trim(col1)||''}''';`)

When postgres executes that, you'll have a valid query. Double quoting the to-be-concatenated bit puts single quotes in the actual command, to break the string and execute the TRIM at that point.

(You also need to double the quotes around the whole string in order to get single quotes around the string in the dynamic statement.)